# Reciprocal of dataframe except first two colums

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the reciprocal of a dataframe, except the first two columns (strings).

I tried:

```
df_sort = df_sort[df_sort.iloc[:,2:]].rdiv(1)
```

But this returns me an error:

> ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not int64

How to get arround this?
At the end, all frames should be reciprocal except the first two.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and clearly explain what is a "*reciprocal a dataframe*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach demonstrated using a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                  'col2': ['c', 'd', 'e'],
                  'col3': [1, 2, 3],
                  'col4': [4, 5, 6]
                  })

m= df.columns[2:]
df[m] = df[m].rdiv(1)

print(df)
```

giving

```
  col1 col2      col3      col4
0    a    c  1.000000  0.250000
1    b    d  0.500000  0.200000
2    c    e  0.333333  0.166667
```